# Any idea How to mark a field as Unique in Quarkus MongoDB Panache

Tags: mongodb, quarkus, quarkus-panache

Any idea How to mark a field as Unique in Quarkus MongoDB Panache.
I tried going through the documentation but found no reference to Unique Constraint could someone guide me.

Comment: instead of insert , use update with `{upsert:true}`

Comment: Solution which I have found is that create index list as `public static final List<IndexModel> INDEXES = List.of(
            new IndexModel(new BasicDBObject("userName", 1), new IndexOptions().unique(true)));` and on application startup `ReactiveMongoCollection<User> collection = reactiveMongoClient.getDatabase("user").getCollection("user", User.class);
        collection.createIndexes(User.INDEXES).await()
                .indefinitely();`

Answer (score 0):

Try some like this

```
mongoCollection.createIndex(Indexes.ascending("userId"), 
                     new IndexOptions().name("userIdIdx").unique(true));
```